Related Rates (Hemisphere)
Help me with the following problem:
A hemispherical sphere of radius 10cm is filled with water at a rate such that the water level is rising 0.4cm/min. Determine the rate at which the bowl is being filled when the height of the water = 5cm.
The answer according to my professor was $30\pi$ $cm^3/min$. I have tried the following but to no avail.
Using the formula for hemisphere's volume: $V=\frac{2}{3}\pi r^3$
I related the height of the hemisphere with the radius using the Pythagorean theorem:
$(r-h)^2+x^2=r^2$ where r is the radius of the sphere, h is the depth of water, and x is the radius of the sphere's cross-section at depth h (see figure below).

Now, using the constant depth h = 5cm and r = 10cm. I calculated x to be $x = \sqrt75$. Also, solving for r using the same relation, I got $r=\frac{h^2+75}{2h}$. This is what I plugged into the volume equation above. Calculating the derivative, I got the final expression for $\frac{dV}{dt}$.
$\frac{dV}{dt}=2\pi(\frac{h^2+75}{2h})^2(\frac{4h^2-2(h^2+75)}{4h^2})(\frac{dh}{dt})$
Plugging in h = 5 and dh/dt = 0.4, I am getting $-80\pi cm^3/min$. Where did I go wrong with my solution?

Hi, welcome. I think the main problem is that, while the tank is hemispherical, the body of water is not.

Also, when differentiating, don't differentiate based on your $r=\frac{r^2+75}{2h}$. When filling water and increasing $h$, $x$ will vary while $r=10~\text{cm}$ is fixed instead.

As I said in my comment, you are assuming that the body of water is a hemisphere. But your drawing shows that it's not.
Choose coordinates so that the circular top of the tank is in the $xz$-plane and the $y$-axis is vertical. The bottom of the tank is at $z=-r$. A cross-section of the water at position $y$ is in the shape of a disk of radius $x$, where $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$. This means that if the tank is full to a level $h$ from the bottom, the volume of water is:
$$
    V(h) = \int_{-r}^{-r+h} \pi (r^2-y^2)\,dy
$$
By the chain rule,
$$
    \frac{dV}{dt} = \frac{dV}{dh} \frac{dh}{dt}
$$
We know $r=10\,\text{cm}$, and at the given moment, $h=5\,\text{cm}$ and $\frac{dh}{dt} = 0.4\,\text{cm}/\text{min}$. We don't need to evaluate the integral to take its derivative. The fundamental theorem of calculus says that
$$
    \frac{dV}{dh} = \pi (r^2-(r-h)^2)
$$
Therefore,
$$
    \frac{dV}{dt} = \pi (10^2 - 5^2)(0.4) = 30 \pi \,\text{cm}^3/\text{min}
$$
